# Java - Generic Type Parameter - Separated Conditions

Tags: java, generics, types, parameters

```
IFoo<L extends List> {
    foo(L<String> listA, L<Integer> listB, ...);
}
```

Is it somehow (evn through some kind of design pattern) to archieve the above behavior? The only way I know is to do the following:

```
IFoo<LA extends List<String>, LB extends List<Integer>, ...> {
    foo(LA listA, LB listB, ...);
}
```

But it is combersome to write and not really clean!

Comment: I'm not perfectly sure; could `<L extends List<? extends Object>>` help? It covers both `List<String>` and `List<Integer>`.

Comment: @Izruo `? extends Object` would just be `?`.

Comment: @1blustone True story. However, I wrote it like this to demonstrate the complete syntax; for example `Object` can be replaced with `Serializable`.

Comment: @1blustone yes but this kind of constraint is not enough!

Comment: @user3596758 What kind of constraint do you need?

Comment: @user3596758 I need a constraint, that only enforces the "outer type" e.g. List but lets me set the "inner/element type" separately!